# Align Button At Bottom of Floating Div - BootStrap Responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to align a button at the bottom of a div that shows when the user scrolls down 600px.

I cannot get the button to align where I want it, as when i use margin-top, when the screensize changes, the button position changes, as I am using % because I want it to be responsive.

Here is the button code and the div code.

Button and div

```
<div class="topMenu"><button type="button" class="btn btn-sky btn-lg btn-float"><a href="#">Get Started</a></button></div>

.topMenu {
display: none;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 14%;
border-top: 1px solid #000;
background: #337AB7;
z-index: 1;
}


$(document).scroll(function () {
var y = $(this).scrollTop();
if (y > 600) {
  $('.topMenu').fadeIn();
} else {
  $('.topMenu').fadeOut();
}

});
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

First, take the link out of the `button` element.  It's not valid HTML.

Next, you need to make your parent div's position `relative` and your button's position `absolute`.  Give your button a `bottom` and `left` value and you should be good.

```
.topMenu {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 1000px;
border-top: 1px solid #000;
background: #337AB7;
z-index: 1;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that has kind of worked for me, but the button is now showing dead right. I will do some messing about with the css and see what I can do. :)